# I/O error occurred when getting message queue from Websphere MQ

Tags: ibm-mq, ioerror

I am currently facing a problem right now wherein I am getting the error I/O error occurred. and I don't know how to pin point where the error occurred. This happened when I get a message queue from the queue. Below is the stack trace of the error.

```
StackTrace:    at AlertTrigger.Data.ServiceAgents.WebSphereAgent.GetMessageQueue(String queueManagerName, String queueName)
   at AlertTrigger.Business.AlertTriggerComponent.QueueListener()
```

Below is the code for the GetMessageQueue:

```
public string GetMessageQueue(string queueManagerName, string queueName)
{
    MQQueueManager mqQueueManager;
    MQQueue storeQueue;
    string result = string.Empty;

    try
    {
        MQMessage mqMessage = new MQMessage();
        MQGetMessageOptions mqGetMessageOption = new MQGetMessageOptions();

        mqGetMessageOption.Options = MQC.MQGMO_WAIT;
        mqGetMessageOption.WaitInterval = 15000;

        mqQueueManager = new MQQueueManager(queueManagerName);

        storeQueue = mqQueueManager.AccessQueue(queueName, MQC.MQOO_INPUT_AS_Q_DEF + MQC.MQOO_FAIL_IF_QUIESCING);

        storeQueue.Get(mqMessage, mqGetMessageOption);

        result = mqMessage.ReadString(mqMessage.DataLength);

    }
    catch (MQException MQEx)
    {
        // Close request Queue if still opened
        if (storeQueue != null && storeQueue.OpenStatus)
            storeQueue.Close();
        // Close Queue manager if still opened
        if (mqQueueManager != null && mqQueueManager.OpenStatus)
            mqQueueManager.Close();

        throw new MQAdapterException(MQEx.Reason.ToString());
        //throw new MQAdapterException("Error Code: " + MQAdapterErrorReasons.GetMQFailureReasonErrorCode(MQEx.Reason));
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw new Exception(ex.Message);
    }
    finally
    {
        // Close request Queue if still opened
        if (storeQueue != null && storeQueue.OpenStatus)
            storeQueue.Close();
        // Close Queue manager if still opened
        if (mqQueueManager != null && mqQueueManager.OpenStatus)
            mqQueueManager.Close();
    }

    return result;
}
```

I hope you can help me on this as I am quite new to WebSphere MQ.

Answer (score 0):

Is this a Java or C# application?  If it is Java, you should do:

```
result = mqMessage.ReadString(mqMessage.getMessageLength());
```